# whisper.cpp takes a long time to start. Can this be avoided?

Tags: shell-script, performance, whisper.cpp

I am using https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/560724/georgi-gerganov 's [whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/) to transcribe recorded interviews. Many of these are short, a minuter or two. The problem is that whisper.cpp takes a looong time to start (I think it is because it loads several GBs into RAM everytime it is launched). **Is there some way around this slow launch? Some way to keep it running even after it has processed a recording?**

I have thousands (probably more than ten thousand) of files I want to transcribe so if it takes a minute to launch everytime, just launching it for 10 000 files will take a week (!).

Any solution must take a specific requirement into consideration: I use a shell script that loops over all files in a directory and then pipes the output to a text file. **One text file for each input file.**

Basically

```
% whisper.cpp inputfil1.wav > inputfile1.txt
% whisper.cpp inputfil2.wav > inputfile2.txt
% whisper.cpp inputfil3.wav > inputfile3.txt
```

(but in a bash for-loop)

The solution must support a new output file for each input file.

Comment: @gerganov Do you know anything?

Comment: I suspect it would be more productive [to file an issue on the project](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/issues).

Comment: @StephenKitt I suspect they have the common c++ sickness, namely that the length of the compiled binary grows exponentially with the count of the levels of the templates. I think, that would have killed C++ since then even if Java does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

If starting the tool is not a cpu bottleneck (it can not be if single-threaded), then you can parallelize it by

```
ls *.wav|\
sed 's/\.wav$//g'|\
xargs -P 8 -n 1 --replace='{}' bash -c 'whisper {}.wav > {}.txt'
```

Note, this is not magic, all the symbols have there their meanings and these are simple meanings what I would happily write to the margin at the right, unfortunately there would be not enough place even if I could do that.

This scripts puts the output of an `ls *.wav` and calls `while thing.wav > thing.txt` - but, it will do that always 8 `whisper` processes will be running in parallel.

Of course if `whisper` is doing hard calculations on all your CPU cores then it won't work - except if the start is slow, the calculation itself is not already.

You also say that the tool requires some GB RAM, obviously if you only have 8 GB then you should not execute processes wanting 8x3GB in the same time. But if you have 32 GB RAM then yes, you can profit by executing 8 x 1GB coincidentally.